# Best way to scope a has_many relationship when find()'ing the parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, has-many, named-scope, default-scope

I'm struggling a bit with understanding default scopes and named scopes with my quiz application.  I'm on rails 3.0.

I have a `Question` model that `has_many` `UserResponse` models.

`Question` has the question `text` and possible `answer_ids`.  `UserResponse` ties `user_id` to a `question_id` and `answer_id`.

When I `find()` a `Question` to display to the user, I don't want to also pull every single `UserResponse`.  By default, I'd like to only pull the `UserResponse` for the current `user_id` to see if they have already answered this question.

How can I create a scope on either the `Question` or `UserResponse` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the scope but I would start out just using the model relationships with something like this query perhaps:

(given question and user)

```
responses = question(question).user_responses(user)
```

Then once working ok I would move onto scopes (if needed) and have:

a scope on the user model for response

```
(Rails3 syntax)  scope :responses_by_user,  labmda { join(:responses) }
```

a scope on the question model for responses

```
(Rails3 syntax)  scope :responses_by_question,  labmda { join(:responses) }
```

Note: I leaning more towards these 'join' approaches in the thought that they will only do 'inner' joins, i.e. only return rows where response records do exist.  I am doing this as opposed to a syntax more like `lambda { where ('user_id = ?', User.id) }
Then you could also chain them together.  Something like`
Question.responses_by_question(question).responses_by_user(user)`